# Cant able to access server by its common name

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have one server  Certificate installed on apache server that have following feilds

1) Common Name : 192.168.0.107

2) Subject Alternative Name :
 IP:192.168.0.108,IP:192.168.0.109

When browser access any of the subject alternative name then browser shows green padlock ( secure connection) but  when i try to access server by its common name browser shows (insecure connection). why this is happening is there any fault  in my certificate? please help me out with this

Note : I have installed root certificate on browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since HTTP over TLS was introduced in 2000 an defined by [RFC2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818) the use of the commonName field has been considered deprecated and if SubjectAlternativeName is present, it must be used.

> If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUSTbe used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used. Although the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is deprecated and  Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead.

Most browsers require currently the SAN extension and do not even accept certificates with only CN. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172626/chrome-requires-san-names-in-certificate-when-will-other-browsers-ie-follow

Comment: Thanx for your reply, but is there any way that i can include both CN and SAN in my certificate ?

Comment: No, the RFC is clear. If SAN is present, it must be used. You could include the CN name in SAN too

Comment: thanx buddy for your help